# XUnit integration Test with IDbContextFactory for a Generic Data Service

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, blazor-server-side, xunit

**tl;dr;
How can I inject the IDbContext factory in a Integration XUnit test?**

I´m working on a Blazor Server project and I am creating a service that uses IDbContextFactory instead of the normal DbContext. The service uses EntityFrameworkCore to communicate with the DB. I need to create integration tests for this service that use the real test database, so I won´t Moq the factory.

This is the basic structure of my service.

```
public class CatalogService<T> : IEntityService<T> where T : CatalogBase
    {

        private readonly IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> _contextFactory;
        private readonly ILogger<T> _logger;

       //The factory is injected via constructor
        public CatalogService(IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> contextFactory, ILogger<T> logger)
        {
            _contextFactory = contextFactory;
            _logger = logger;
        }    
       //... All the functions
    }
```

I also have a fixture where some seed data can be created

```
public class TestDatabaseFixture
    {
        private const string ConnectionString = @"my_connection";

        private static readonly object _lock = new();
        private static bool _databaseInitialized;

        public TestDatabaseFixture()
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                if (!_databaseInitialized)
                {
                    using (var context = CreateContext())
                    {
                        context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                        context.Database.EnsureCreated();


                        //Create Seed Data for Brands
                        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                            context.PcMarcas.Add(new PcBrand { Description = $"Brand {(i + 1).ToString("0000") }" });
                        }                      
                        
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }

                    _databaseInitialized = true;
                }
            }
        }



        public ApplicationDbContext CreateContext()
        { 
            return new ApplicationDbContext(
            new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .UseSqlServer(ConnectionString)
                .Options);
        }

        public IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> CreateDbContextFactory() { 
            //How do I return the context factory? <---
        }

    }
```

I know how to moq my logger and create a normal DBContext, but I´m not sure how to inject the factory in the test

```
[Fact]
public async Task GetAsync_ShouldReturnAnItem()
{
    //Setup ------------------------------------------------------
    var contextFactory = Fixture.CreateDbContextFactory(); //from the fixture

    var logger = Mock.Of<ILogger<PcMarca>>();
    var service = new CatalogService<PcMarca>(contextFactory, logger);

    //Act  -------------------------------------------------------


    //Assert  ----------------------------------------------------

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to implement a `IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>` yourself.

To reuse your existing code to create an `ApplicationDbContext` instance, you can choose to implement that `IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>` as an inner class of your `TestDatabaseFixture`.

For brevity below code doesn't include the constructor.

```
public class TestDatabaseFixture
{
    public class ApplicationDbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext()
        {
            return CreateApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }

    private const string ConnectionString = @"my_connection";

    public ApplicationDbContext CreateContext()
    {
        return CreateApplicationDbContext();
    }

    public IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> CreateDbContextFactory()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContextFactory();
    }

    private static ApplicationDbContext CreateApplicationDbContext()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext(
            new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
           .UseSqlServer(ConnectionString)
           .Options);
    }
}
```